# How to use pyomo+nlpk properly, it is too slow

Tags: pyomo

Problem scale：I have 100000 variables and 3 constraints.
Ten hours have passed，the above problem was not solved.
How to optimize the problem.

> > pyomo solve pp.py --solver=glpk

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.I = Set(initialize = [i for i in range(N)])
model.x = Var(model.I, within = NonNegativeIntegers, bounds = (0,1))
model.pctr = Param(model.I, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize=data.pctr.to_dict()) # pctri
model.pcvr = Param(model.I, within = NonNegativeReals, initialize=data.pcvr.to_dict()) # pcvri
model.mkt_ecpm = Param(model.I, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=data.mkt_ecpm.to_dict(), default=0.0) # mkti
model.v = Param(model.I, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=v_init_click, default=0.0)
model.c = Param(model.I, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=c_init, default=0.0) 
def constrs_budget(model,i):
    return sum(model.x[i]*model.c[i] for i in model.I) <= budget 
model.constrs_budget = Constraint(model.I, rule=constrs_budget)
def constrs_cpc(model, i):
    return sum(model.x[i]*(model.c[i]-cpc*model.v[i]) for i in model.I) <= 0.0
model.constrs_cpc = Constraint(model.I, rule=constrs_cpc)
model.constrs_x = Constraint(model.I, rule=constrs_x)
model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_cpi, sense=maximize)
```